# review_save_after event observer is not running correctly

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I am using Magento 1.8 version. I have written an observer that has to run when admin save a product review with status "Approved". And i have created a ratings attribute for every product with multiselect and it should automatically update every time when admin save the review for a product.

**Note:** Reviews are in Reports/Reviews/Product Reviews.

**etc/Config.xml Code:**

```
<review_save_after>
    <observers>
        <efkadminhtml>
            <class>efkadminhtml/observer</class>
            <method>ratingsUpdate</method>
        </efkadminhtml>
    </observers>
</review_save_after>
```

**mode/Observer Code**

```
public function ratingsUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    $statusId = $object->getStatusId();

    if($statusId == 1) {
        $common = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/common');
        $attribute = $common->getAttribute('ratings');
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $productId = $object->getEntityPkValue();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $avgRating = Mage::getBlockSingleton('efkreports/product_allReviews')->getAvgReview($product->getId());

        Mage::log($avgRating);
        Mage::log($attribute->getOptionId(round($avgRating)));
        $product->setRatings($attribute->getOptionId(round($avgRating)));
        //$product->setRatings(round($avgRating));
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

When admin is attempting to save review for a product, the above observer code is executing and review is updating correctrly but product is getting previous review value rather than latest updated review.

I wrote `<review_save_after>` but it getting previous value. What is the event called after **"Save Review"** Is that correct or not?

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After lot of research I got solution...:-) But we may do this very easily.

```
public function ratingsUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        $data = $object->getData();

        $newRatings = $data['ratings'];
        $reviewId = $data['review_id'];

        $newSumRatings = 0;
        foreach($newRatings as $r) {
            $value = $r % 5;
            $newSumRatings += ($value) ? $value : 5;
        }
        $newAvgRating = $newSumRatings;

        $statusId = $object->getStatusId();
        if($statusId == 1) {
            $common = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/common');
            $attribute = $common->getAttribute('ratings');
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

            $productId = $object->getEntityPkValue();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

            $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
                ->addEntityFilter('product', (int)$productId)
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes();

            $avg = 0;

            if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
                    $temp = 0;
                    if($reviewId == $review->getReviewId()) {
                        $sum += $newSumRatings;
                    } else {
                        foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
                            $temp += $vote->getPercent() / 20;
                        }
                        $sum += $temp;  
                    }
                }

                $avg = $sum / (count($reviews) * 3);
            }

            $product->setRatings($attribute->getOptionId(round($avg)));
            $product->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<review_save_after>
 <observers>
    <efkadminhtml>
        <type>singleton</type> 
        <class>efkadminhtml/observer</class>
        <method>ratingsUpdate</method>
    </efkadminhtml>
</observers>
```

add Type and then Try

Comment: I have put that line **<type>singleton</type>**. But no effect still getting same problem.

Comment: try to log using Mage::log('test'). and please let me know

Comment: Mage::log('test') is displaying **test**. Observer function is executing.

Comment: Then Your observer is working fine

Comment: I already mentioned that observer code is executing. But when iam getting avgRatings for that product it is not getting updated ratings.

Comment: http://www.letsmakeitgo.com/blog/2011/06/magento-add-product-ratings-programmatically-or-migrating-reviews-and-ratings-to-magento/

follow this link for coding