# Rating Filter in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter, ratings

I want to implement Rating Filter in layered navigation sidebar. But I have no idea how to proceed or where to begin..  [Read this article](http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/).. got little idea but still don't know to implement rating filtration. Somebody can guide me on this?

**EDIT:**
After searching a lot I came across [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12335/33229). Then I made an attribute Rating with dropdown value of 1,2,3,4,5. Now Whenever I am setting the value with observer it is setting value with the product(checking using  $product->getData()) but when I am checking in the product edit(adminhtml) is not setting the value.

Also I have only one rating instead of 3( Have only Overall rating). So How I am suppose to get only avg rating of one product.

here'S MY Current code:

```
 public function ratingsUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        $data = $object->getData();
        $newRatings = $data['ratings'];
        $reviewId = $data['review_id'];

        $statusId = $object->getStatusId();
        if ($statusId == 1) {

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $productId = $object->getEntityPkValue();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                                        ->load($productId);

        if ($summaryData['rating_summary'] == 90):
           // Mage::log($summaryData['rating_summary'], null, 'size1.log', true);
            $product->setRating(5);//
            $product->save();
        endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function ratingsUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        $data = $object->getData();

        $newRatings = $data['ratings'];
        $reviewId = $data['review_id'];

        $newSumRatings = 0;
        foreach ($newRatings as $r) {
            $value = $r % 5;
            $newSumRatings += ($value) ? $value : 5;
        }
        $statusId = $object->getStatusId();
        if ($statusId == 1) {

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $productId = $object->getEntityPkValue();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

            $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                    ->getResourceCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addEntityFilter('product', (int) $productId)
                    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                    ->setDateOrder()
                    ->addRateVotes();

            $avg = 0;
            $sum=0;
            if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
                    $temp = 0;
                    if ($reviewId == $review->getReviewId()) {
                        $sum += $newSumRatings;
                    } else {
                        foreach ($review->getRatingVotes() as $vote) {
                            $temp += $vote->getPercent() / 20;
                        }
                        $sum += $temp;
                    }
                }

                $rating = $sum / (count($reviews));
            }

            if ($rating == 5) {
                $product->setRatings(11); //
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 4) {
                $product->setRatings(12); //
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 3) {
                $product->setRatings(13); //
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 2) {
                $product->setRatings(14); //
                $product->save();
            } else {
                $product->setRatings(15); //
                $product->save();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your article.
I have implement and i want to share with everyone about "rating fiter" feature

Step 1 : create a Extension.
*app/code/local/Packages/RatingFilter/etc/config.xml*

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Packages_RatingFilter>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packages_RatingFilter>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <ratingfilter>
            <class>Packages_RatingFilter_Model</class>
        </ratingfilter>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <ratingfilter_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Packages_RatingFilter</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </ratingfilter_setup>
    </resources>
    <events>
        <review_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Packages_RatingFilter_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Packages_RatingFilter_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updateRatingFilterAttribute</method>
                </Packages_RatingFilter_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </review_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Step2: Setup attribute
*app/code/local/Packages/RatingFilter/sql/ratingfilter_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php*

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'rating_filter', [
    'group' => 'General',
    'label' => 'Rating',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'default' => '',
    'class' => '',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'source'    => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => true,
    'filterable_in_search' => true,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'option'     => [
        'values' => [
            1 => 'One star',
            2 => 'Two stars',
            3 => 'Three stars',
            4 => 'Four stars',
            5 => 'Five stars',
        ]
    ],

]);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Step3: create observer

```
class Packages_RatingFilter_Model_Observer
{
    public function updateRatingFilterAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        $data = $object->getData();

        $newRatings = $data['ratings'];
        $reviewId = $data['review_id'];

        $newSumRatings = 0;
        foreach ($newRatings as $r) {
            $value = $r % 5;
            $newSumRatings += ($value) ? $value : 5;
        }
        $statusId = $object->getStatusId();
        if ($statusId == 1) {

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $productId = $object->getEntityPkValue();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

            $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addEntityFilter('product', (int) $productId)
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes();

            $avg = 0;
            $sum = 0;

            if (count($reviews) > 0) {
                foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
                    $temp = 0;
                    if ($reviewId == $review->getReviewId()) {
                        $sum += $newSumRatings;
                    } else {
                        foreach ($review->getRatingVotes() as $vote) {
                            $temp += $vote->getPercent() / 20;
                        }
                        $sum += $temp;
                    }
                }

                $rating = $sum / (count($reviews));
            }

            if ($rating == 5) {
                $product->setRatingFilter(24); // option id
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 4) {
                $product->setRatingFilter(23);
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 3) {
                $product->setRatingFilter(22);
                $product->save();
            } elseif ($rating >= 2) {
                $product->setRatingFilter(21);
                $product->save();
            } else {
                $product->setRatingFilter(20);
                $product->save();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Haris, where to create observer code file location can you tell me?

Comment: I want to implement this model to my store, pls tell me

Comment: I was created observer file "app/code/local/Packages/RatingFilter/Model/Observer/Observer.php"

Comment: there is no change in layered navigation?