# How to show product rating on filter magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection

How to show product rating on filter Magento. I am trying to show filters in the form of product rating stars. Please help, how to show?

Comment: Plase check this link ,may be it's helpfull https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108124/rating-filter-in-layered-navigation

Comment: I don't understand that where i paste that code who showing recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This solution is incomplete for an already running store.

Please follow below steps to have a basic idea:

- Create an attribute for that and add that attribute to layered navigation.
- Observe the event **`review_save_after`**. In this event, you can get the product and review summary, and update your attribute value from this every time when a review is saved.

You can check the similar logic's code in the answer from @The Hien at this [URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108124/rating-filter-in-layered-navigation).

Also, you can try this [extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/sunarc-filter-product-by-rating.html), if you don't want to code yourself.