# Declaring observer from xml for review form submit issue

Tags: event-observer, xml, review

Hey I am trying to declare an observer from xml but it doesn't work. This is my xml:

```
<config>
<global>
            <events>
                <review_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule_review_save_after>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_Review</class>
                            <method>redirectSuccess</method>
                        </mynamespace_mymodule_review_save_after>
                    </observers>
                </review_save_after>
            </events>
</global>
</config>
```

I put an  exit in my `redirectSuccess` function, but it doesn't go there. I guess something is wrong with my xml. Can you help me ? thx

Comment: Can you post the full `config.xml` as well as the `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_Review` class please ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/review-save-after-event-observer-is-not-running-correctly

Comment: I already tried that but it doesnt work